# Flutter Server Side Events, reactive UI

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, server-sent-events

I'm trying to get my application to respond to an SSE server-sent-events stream. The stream has many types of events that appear, and parts of the application are to update *only* if the *type* of event that I receive is associated with that UI element.

Sample json stream response (For example here, I wouldn't want to change the UI if I get a heartbeat):

```
event:heartbeat
data:{"type":"heartbeat"}

event:gwy
data:{"a":532289,"lastUpdatedDateInMilliseconds":1587490669503,"t":1587490669503,"g":12479,"api":0,"cellSignalStrength":15}

event:gwy
data:{"a":532289,"lastUpdatedDateInMilliseconds":1587490694685,"t":1587490694685,"g":12479,"api":0,"cellSignalStrength":15}
```

The format of this data is a subset of the Global data variable (The event should replace that part of the global variable).

Any pointers or resources greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you going to check if there is new data?sockets or http requests every period of time?

Comment: Thank you for the enquiry. I have a HTTP GET request that I call once, and it returns a stream of data (json events with type: heartbeat, gwy, etc..).

Comment: how many pages depend on this stream? can you please provide more details

Comment: 1 page depends on the stream. The event will change the status of a UI component to 1 state or another - essentially 'on' or 'off'. Several UI components may be effected by the stream, but only ever one at a time - 1 event corresponds to 1 UI element. So the JSON will come along the stream, which may or may not update a UI component, depending on whether that UI component belongs to the json payload

Comment: ok so you should use a stream builder, you specify a stream, listen to it, and build and update your UI accordingly, refer to the documentation in flutter.dev to see an example about it please

Answer (score 5):

I know that you've got the answer, but in case of wanting to parse the streamed value, here's the code that I use, it extracts the event and the actual data

```
import "package:http/http.dart";

http.Client client = http.Client();

http.Request request = http.Request("GET", Uri.parse('your url'));
request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";
request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";

Future<http.StreamedResponse> response = client.send(request);
print("Subscribed!");
response.then((streamedResponse) => streamedResponse.stream.listen((value) {
  final parsedData = utf8.decode(value);
  print(parsedData);

  //event:heartbeat
  //data:{"type":"heartbeat"}
        
  final eventType = parsedData.split("\n")[0].split(":")[1];
  print(eventType);
  //heartbeat
  final realParsedData = json.decode(parsedData.split("data:")[1]) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if (realParsedData != null) {
  // do something
  }
}, onDone: () => print("The streamresponse is ended"),),);
```

Comment: How do you do, if you want to cancel the subscription (created by the .listen)?

Comment: @Monta The "listen" function returns a "StreamSubscription" object, on which you can call "cancel" to cancel the subscription. More specifically this code: "streamedResponse.stream.listen()". For the above code, you need to do some customization, hit me up to update the code if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I figured it out searching on the web